# Verify that the set of polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

First let $\mathbb{F} = (\mathbb{Q}[x], +_\mathbb{F},\times_\mathbb{F})$ be the structure such $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is the set of all polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $+_\mathbb{F}$ and $\times_\mathbb{F}$ are the ordinary addition and multiplication operations on polynomials.

I already have proved by other exercises that $\mathbb{F}$ is a integral domain, thus i will skip the axioms for integral domains and start by checking the existence of a multiplicative inverse for every element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Let $f$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, if there is some other polynomial $g$ which is the multiplicative inverse of $f$, then we can satisfy $fg = 1_\mathbb{F}$, that is $[fg(0) = 1_\mathbb{Q} \land fg(n)=0, \forall n\gt0]$, but if $f(0) = 0_\mathbb{Q}$, we have $fg(0) = 0_\mathbb{Q}\times g(0) = 0_\mathbb{Q} \neq 1_\mathbb{Q}$

Therefore any polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ which have the first coefficient equal $0_\mathbb{Q}$, dont have a multiplicative inverse, I think this suffice to show that $\mathbb{F}$ is not a field.

Comment: This looks ok, but there's a much simpler proof. First, observe that since $\mathbb Q$ is an integral domain, $\deg f\cdot \deg g=\deg(f\cdot g)$. So, if there exists some polynomial $g$ such that $x^2g=1$, then $\deg x^2\cdot\deg g=0$, so $\deg g=-2$, which is not possible.

Comment: @DonThousand just a minor point that should be $degf+deg g=deg f.g$

Comment: Its really more clear and simple, I will use deg when checking the second condition $fg(n)=0, \forall n \gt 0$, but I finished not looking into this because the first condition failed. Thanks for showing this way.

Comment: @DonThousand in some ways your proof and OP's are using the two non-trivial facts about polynomial rings. OP's proof is that there is a ring map $\mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}$ with a non-trivial kernel (evaluate at 0, stuff divisible by $x$) so the domain can't be a field, and your proof is that there is surjective a monoid map $(\mathbb{Q}[x] \setminus 0, \times) \to (\mathbb{N}, +)$ taking $1$ to $0$, so the domain can't be a group (and hence the original ring can't be a field).

Comment: @hunter I agree that its non-trivial, but it's not that complicated of an assumption. Proving that $\deg$ is a map from $\mathbb Q[x]\to\mathbb N$ satisfying $\deg f+\deg g=\deg(f\cdot g)$ is actually quite easy.

Comment: @DonThousand your approach is also definitely pedagogically more useful for OP, as degree is of course a very useful notion to be aware of when studying polynomials, and your argument also shows that *any* non-constant element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is non-invertible. (+1) however, correct me if I'm missing something obvious, but what OP wrote is not *quite* right, is it? in particular, they write that, if $f$ and $g$ are inverses, then $fg(n)=0$ for all $n>0$. of course they want $fg(n)=1$. it doesn't change their argument at all but I thought it was worth noting

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Yes, I didn't notice that! Good catch +1. And yes, I wanted to include a degree argument since it is more representative of the proof style that is used in these sorts of proofs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument works, but you can make it even simpler - all you need is one non-zero element without an inverse. We will show that $x$ has no inverse.

Suppose that $x f(x) = 1$ for some polynomial $f(x)$. Then $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ for some elements $a_i\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then
$$
xf(x) = \sum_{i=0}^na_ix^{i+1} = 1.
$$
In particular (by definition of polynomials), comparing constant coefficients gives $0=1$, a contradiction, so we are done.

**Note:** We could have made things even easier by evaluating at zero (i.e. if $xf(x) = 1$ then $0f(0) = 1$ so $0 = 1$), but I think it's better to compare coefficients, because then we only make use of the definition of polynomials. Evaluating the polynomial automatically makes use of (slightly) more sophisticated machinery, which in this case is not needed.